# accessing class that creates list from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following Class which basically creates a list of categories (called commands, I know it's weird)

Here is CommandDB.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TM_non_deploy
{
    public partial class CommandDB
    {
        private static string connectionString = "blah";

        public static List<Command> GetCommands()
        {
            List<Command> commandList = new List<Command>();

            DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_tm_commands";

            connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            Command command;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                command = new Command();

                command.ID = reader.GetOrdinal("id");
                command.Name = reader["name"].ToString();

                commandList.Add(command);
            }

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();

            return commandList;

        }

        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return connectionString;
        }

    }
}
```

my question is hopefully pretty simple, how do I, in my main page, access this list so that it calls the function and returns all the commands so I can iterate thru them? I thought it might be something like `List<CommandDB> commandList = new List<CommandDB.>GetCommands();` but I haven't really had any luck figuring it out thru the msdn.

Comment: you guys got it, thanks. sorry, i'd mark all of you as right, but it wont let me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Command> myCommands = CommandDB.GetCommands();
foreach(Command com in myCommands)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I think this is the syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This method is static and so it should be called like this

```
 List<Command> commandList = CommandDB.GetCommands();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var commandList = CommandDB.GetCommands(); //implicit type detection by compiler
```

Answer (score 1):

> A static member belongs to the type
>   itself rather than to a specific
>   object.
>
> A static member cannot be referenced
>   through an instance. Instead, it is
>   referenced through the type name.

```
List<Command> commandList = CommandDB.GetCommands();
```

---

Refer to [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)